# Disable large UIImages for UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

One core feature from my app is that the User can use his own images.
But the image size should be restricted to certain size. For example the User shouldn't be allowed to load panorama pictures in the imageView. What would be the best way to restrict this?

Should I just do an if statement after the imagePickerController? And what would be a good maximum size?

Comment: You could easily set your imageView contentMode to aspectSizeToFit or Fill.This way you don't need to worry about image size restrictions?

Comment: No I have to do some memory intensiv work later and if the image is to big the it crashes with Signal 9.

Comment: Why don't you just down sample the image to the actual size of the image view before you assign it to the image view; then you won't have any extra pixels in memory. http://nshipster.com/image-resizing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `image.size` property, and then perform calculations against that to check for excessive size, or ratios you do not support.

For example, panoramic images tend to have 2,3 or even 4:1 ratios of width to height, which would make them easy to detect.

Answer (score 1):

You could also add a UIImage extension to resize the image after the user picks it.

```
extension UIImage {

    func resizeImage(_ targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {

        // This is the rect that we've calculated out and this is what is actually used below
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: targetSize.width, height: targetSize.height)

        // Actually do the resizing to the rect using the ImageContext stuff
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(targetSize, false, 1.0)
        self.draw(in: rect)
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage!
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as! UIImage
    let resizedImage = pickedImage.resizeImage(CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
}
```

Optimal size will likely depend on your requirements and why you're having crashes.